# Warning "A category is required" in the Actions Console

Tags: google-smart-home

I constantly receive a warning "A category is required" in the Actions Console for some Smart Action (Deploy -> Directory information).

[image]

As I understand category could be set in the Deploy -> Directory information -> Additional Information. But there I see only "Smart Home Business Partnership Requirements" with an invitation to fill out the "Brand Permissions Form". Following this link leads to a 403 error.
[image]

How can I set the category to Smart Actions?

Note: some other Actions with the same settings do not show such a warning.

Comment: This category field is not present for smart home Actions. If you are still seeing this warning with a fresh smart home project, please file an issue in the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your project might not be set up properly as the category field is not present for smart home Actions and it is automatically selected for every project. Please set up a new project in the AoG console (https://console.actions.google.com/), and select Smart Home project type at creation.
The. If you’re still facing any issues after that then please file an issue in the public bug tracker